# If I SET ARRAYSIZE 1 in SQL*Plus, the records are still fetched in pairs. Why?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I thought about writing a *simple* `tail -f` like utility to "trace" the progress of some figures within the database:

```
create or replace function tail_f return varchar2_tab pipelined as
   n number;
begin

    loop
      exit when ...

      select count(*) into n from ... where ...;

      pipe row(sysdate || ' n= ' || n);
      dbms_lock.sleep(60);
    end loop;

    return;
end tail_f;
```

And then I'd like to `select * from table(tail_f)` in SQL*Plus.

In order to fetch the rows one by one, I `SET ARRAYSIZE 1`. Yet, the records (except the first one) are fetched in pairs.

Is there an explanation for this and how can I get the records as soon as one is piped?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Metalink bug 9103343 states:

> This is expected behaviour.  SQL*Plus is written in oci and oci has a
>   default  prefetch value of 1 row.  However prefetch upon a fetch (as
>   opposed to upon  an execute) only takes place when you are not
>   performing an array fetch, so  when arraysize is 1.   Regardless of
>   arraysize the first fetch in the trace is always 1 row as 1 row  is
>   prefetched on the execute.  Then it either performs a scalar fetch, so
>   one  requested row plus one prefetched row, or it performs an array
>   fetch so you  see eg :   a) arraysize = 1, fetches are:  1, 2, 2, ...
>   b) arraysize = 2, fetches are:  1, 2, 2, ... c) arraysize = 5, fetches
>   are:  1, 5, 5, ...

Also see Metalink doc 1265916.1

Comment: Thans for confirming my suspicion with the metalink note.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a quirk of SQL*Plus and `arraysize` rather than pipelined functions - the following demonstrates the same effect:

```
create or replace function pause return integer as
begin
  dbms_lock.sleep(2);
  return 1;
end;
/

select pause from dual connect by level<10;
```

You can (sort of) workaround the issue by selecting the rows twice and discarding every second one:

```
select /*+ ordered first_rows(1) */ *
from table(tail_f) cross join (select level from dual connect by level<=2);
```